# How to return result after fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

The task is to make an async request to the images API (pixabay) and return data. I'm trying to make it using fetch, am I right? But in this case I'm getting an empty returned value. What can I do with it?

```js
function myfunc(){
  fetch(URL).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
  }).then(function(hitsJSON) {
      hitsJSON.hits.forEach(item => {
          let resultItem = {
              id: item.id,
              url: item.previewURL,
              tags: item.tags
          }
          results.push(resultItem);
      });
  });
  return {
      query: query,
      images: results
  };
 }
```

Comment: Where are you defining `results`/`query`?

Answer (score 0):

You could return the result of your fetch request by extending the way you use promises in `myfunc()`.

The usual approach is to return the promise that is created by `fetch()`, from `myfunc()`. That way, when you call `myfunc()` you can add a function handler  to `.then()` that gets executed (with the fetch result) after your request has completed:

```
function myfunc(){

  // Add return here to return the fetch's promise
  return fetch(URL).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
  }).then(function(hitsJSON) {

      var results = []

      hitsJSON.hits.forEach(item => {
          let resultItem = {
              id: item.id,
              url: item.previewURL,
              tags: item.tags
          }
          results.push(resultItem);
      });

      // Return result here when request is complete
      return {
          query: 'query',
          images: results
      };
  });
 }


 // Use myfunc() like this:    
 myfunc().then( function( results ) {

   console.log(results)

 })
```